# Настройки андроид приложения

Tags: android, java, настройка

Всем добрый вечер! Всех православных с праздником!!!
Пишу приложение, и встала необходимость работы с SharedPreferences для создания настроек приложения.
Делаю следующим образом:

```
SharedPreferences sPref;
void saveSet() {
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor ed = sPref.edit();
ed.putString("key", "Например HEllo");
ed.comhit();
}
Далее для загрузки информации из SharedPreferences:
void loadSet() {
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedtext = sPref.getString("key","");
ВЫВОД ТЕКСТА - не суть важно куда
}
```

Если я вызываю обе функции внутри одной активности то все прекрасно работает, как только я создаю другую активность и из нее получить сохраненную строку то выводит у меня только дефолтное значение, в моем случае "". 
С первого взгляда можно подумать, что все дело в

```
sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Но я менял MODE_PRIVATE и на MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE | MODE_WORLD_READABLE
и на MODE_MULTI_PROCESS но ничего не выходит.
Помогите разобраться!!! Плиз!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Помоему из документации все понятно:

> public SharedPreferences getPreferences (int mode)
> Retrieve a SharedPreferences object for accessing preferences that are private to this activity

Вместо этого можешь использовать:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Видимо я читать разучился!

Comment: пожалуйста